# Will new Version(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute.Version) always succeed?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

Will `new Version(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute.Version)` always succeed?

This is my code.

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Version>() != null);
var ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var attributes = ass.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false).Cast<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>();
var versionAttribute = attributes.Single();
return new Version(versionAttribute.Version)
```

Comment: @Nick because `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute` can contain any arbitrary string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No:

```
[assembly:AssemblyFileVersion("fred")]
static class program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var attributes = ass.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute), false).Cast<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>();
        var versionAttribute = attributes.Single();
        var ver = new Version(versionAttribute.Version);        
    }
}
```

Note that this *does* generate a *warning*:

> Warning   1   Assembly generation -- The version 'Fred' specified for the 'file version' is not in the normal 'major.minor.build.revision' format

But a *warning* doesn't stop it happening.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if attribute AssemblyFileVersionAttribute is defined in AssemblyInfo.cs. The above code will throw an exception if `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]` is commented in AssemblyInfo.cs.